# cannot execute "update-grub"

Tags: grub2

update-grub returns:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 12: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LI­NUX=acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor: not found
```

Moreover, the *apt-get upgrade* command is not executed successfully, it ends by this message:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.config: 12: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LI­NUX=acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor: not found
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

grub file: /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LI­NUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

what's wrong with grub? I did not touch it!

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line in `/etc/default/grub` is not correct:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LI­NUX="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

It should say

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LI­NUX=""
```

And your boot parameters `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` should be placed in the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

edit the file:

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

and correct the two lines so after your edit you have:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LI­NUX=""
```

Save the file, exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: It solved the problem. Do you know why did it happen?

Comment: @PuyaAmiri well, someone put those boot parameters there... not you?